# Cross Compilation for C applications using Eclipse

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, cross-compiling

I'm developing a java application which uses native code with `JNI`, so I developped a `C shared library` using `Eclipse with the CDT plugin` on Linux Redhat. Everything works fine since I can launch my java application and call the native methods without any problem. But my problem is, I need to compile my code on every platform `(Linux, Windows, x86/x64)`. It's not a problem to get the `libXXX.so` file but I also need a `.dll` to run on Windows, except I can't just compile my code on it, I need a way to do that locally on Linux with Eclipse. So I am looking for some simple solutions to do that locally with Eclipse using cross compilation.

I've made some researches but I can't find a real tutorial to explain how to do that, each time people say to compile on the specified platform. So if someone could help me with this that would be great.

My configuration is : Linux RedHat, Eclipse Juno, CDT plugin 8.1

Comment: You will need to test and debug on the target platform anyway, so why bother with cross-compilation? It's not like you are targeting an embedded system incapable of running a compiler.

Comment: It would be useful when you just have a little bit of native code and you want to avoid multiple compilations on another computer (if you are allowed to install a compiler on it of course). And if you have a little modification to do, you need an usb stick to tranfer your code, find a windows computer, compile your code, get the dll, put it in your project, and finally test your application just to discover that you forgot a printf and have to do it all again. So if it's possible to compile for both linux and windows on the same computer at the same time, it would be great haha

Comment: You can compile on the same computer, just set up a virtual machine and off you go.

Comment: Yes that would be a good solution except that I can't do it because my company restricts access on local machines.

Comment: Why installing a VM on your local machine is any different from installing a cross-compiler?  If one is restricted, the other ought to be too.

Comment: Yes you're right, I thought about using a remote computer too, using the network.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Linux -> Windows cross compiler. The [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) tools would do the job, but, last I checked, they only provide binary downloads to run *on* Windows (i.e. not a cross-compiler). There are some (old) instructions for building your own [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW).

The [CodeBench](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/platforms/ia32-windows) compiler is probably exactly what you want, but it's not free (there is a free trial though). It's basically a professional build of the MinGW tools, and comes with it's own customized Eclipse so there's no fiddling about needed in that department.

A quick google also comes up with [these tools on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-cross/), but I've not tried them.

Comment: I found a MinGW running on linux. It seems to work properly because it generates a .so file but I don't know how to configure Eclipse to tell it that I want a .dll file.

Comment: Generating a DLL file is not straight-forward at all. I don't know if Eclipse knows how to do it automatically. Even Visual Studio requires you to write some special files with the symbol exports (or did last I tried, years ago).